# Problem writing JSON to file using Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write a JSON file to the file system using Python. When I go to read the file there's nothing there. I think I'm doing something else wrong.

This is my code:

```
    today = datetime.today()
    output_dir = "../../../json/iam"
    output_file = output_dir + 'pol-aws-secrets-manager-' + user_name + today +'.json'
    policy_doc = {"blah":"blah"}
    with open(output_file, 'w+') as writer:
        json.dump(policy_doc,writer)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look in `../../../json/` for your files.

You're building your filenames by sticking strings together, which is very error prone. In this case you've forgotten a `/`, so instead of getting files like

```
../../../json/iam/foo.json
```

you're getting files like

```
../../../json/iamfoo.json
```

A much safer strategy would be to use something like [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) or [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the response above. I tried your code and it created a file with `{"blah":"blah"}` without any issues.

The problem could be in the path you specified.